# How to retrieve the Tooltip values of a chart

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I want to retrieve the tool tip values of the chart available in the http://money.rediff.com/companies/L-T-Finance-Holdings-Ltd/17027392. I have tried the below code.

```
test=browser.div(:id,"div_bse_graph").div(:id,"bseChart").elements(:css=>"canvas")
test.each do |p|
  p.hover
  puts browser.div(:id,"div_bse_graph").div(:id,"bseChart").div(:class,"jqplot-highlighter-tooltip").text
end
```

Output:
11:56, 70.80
11:56, 70.80
11:56, 70.80
11:56, 70.80
11:56, 70.80
11:56, 70.80
11:56, 70.80

Please help me how to retrieve all the tool tip values.

Comment: I do not see a chart on that page. Tried both FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The data is ajaxed in so your concept will not work as expected. Took me a little while to find the call but this is what you are looking for

http://money.rediff.com/money1/chart_1day_new.php?companyCode=17027392&all=1

Substitute the company code for any one you want and parse the XML. e.g.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('http://money.rediff.com/money1/chart_1day_new.php?companyCode=17027392&all=1')
doc.xpath("//graph/set").map{|element| [element.attributes["name"].value,element.attributes["value"].value]}
#=>[["09:15", "71.90"], ["09:16", "71.35"], ["09:17", "71.35"], ["09:18", "71.45"],
   ["09:19", "71.45"], ["09:20", "71.50"], ["09:21", "71.60"], ["09:22", "71.50"],....]
```

I truncated the response because it is very long but this will give you a 2 dimensional array of all those points in the graph represented as [time,value]